# Unhandled Promise rejection on try/catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose I have an async function

```
static async update (id, data){
  try { 
     //async function below
     _DB.putsomedata()

     return true
  } catch(e){
    //log errors
  }
}
```

And although I don't need the result of `_DB.putsomedata()`, I still need to know if the `update()` function finished without errors.

I did some testing and noticed that the result will always return true (thats expected), but in case it fails, the the error is never caught in the catch block, and that raises an unhandled exception.

Can somebody explain the behaviour?

Comment: because you didn't put `await` before calling the `async` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `_DB.putsomedata` is an `async` function, you need to **`await`** it. Otherwise its Promise will simply continue in the background, where it eventually fails and produces the error. Your code will have continued on ahead in the meantime and the `try..catch` block will have long been exited.

Comment: So i have no option but to use await? I was hoping to increase the speed by not waiting for the results which i don't need, but still handle the exception incase it fails.

Comment: The alternative is to chain a `catch`: `_DB.putsomedata().catch(console.error)`. But then your `update` function doesn't need to be `async`, because it's not.

Answer (score 0):

putsomedata function is asynchonious, so the return statment in compute just after marking putsomedata as computable (and not launch, as for synchronious function).

putsomedata return probably a promise, which will be resolved after, when cpu will be avaiable.

you can use .promise() .then() .catch() functions